# How to have a button in a datagrid template that will remove the item when clicked

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I would like to use a datatemplate for my datagrid columns and have a button for each item. I would like the item to be removed if the user clicks the button. I am using the MVVM pattern. How would I accomplish this?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Width="50" Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveItemCommand}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
  public ItemViewModel()
  {
    RemoveCommand = new MyCommand(Remove);
  }

  public event EventHandler ItemRemoved;
  public ICommand RemoveCommand { get; private set; }

  private void Remove()
  {
    // Whatever it takes to remove item from your data store
    service.Remove(this.Data);

    var removeItem = ItemRemoved;
    if (removeItem != null)
      removeItem(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}

public class ListViewModel
{
  public ListViewModel(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> items)
  {
    ItemVMs=new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(items);
    foreach (var item in ItemVMs)
      item.ItemRemoved += RemoveSelectedItem;
  }

  public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemVMs { get; private set; }

  private void RemoveSelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var item = sender as ItemViewModel;
    item.ItemRemoved -= RemoveSelectedItem;
    ItemVMs.Remove(item);
  }
}
```

Each item's RemoveCommand would be bound to its button in your DataGrid. It sounds like you already have that part done. Make the ListViewModel's ItemVMs property the data source for your DataGrid.

Comment: Making items responsible for removing themselves is much simpler (and more easily testable) than Will's approach of binding to a command in the items' parent.

Comment: This approach was simpler to implement and works well. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The View is responsible for this.  You can simply use codebehind to control the visibility of UI elements in response to user actions in the UI.

Sometimes, it is better to be practical than be rigidly dogmatic.

---

Well, now that you have edited your question, it becomes a completely different matter.

Your DataGrid should be bound to a collection of items.

Your button should be bound to a command on the ViewModel, and the CommandParameter should be the Model that particular row is bound to.

```
<DataTemplate>
      <Button Content="Remove" 
              Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveItemCommand, 
                                ElementName=theWindow}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Note some important things here.  We need, from within the template, to bind to an ICommand on the ViewModel.  The ViewModel is the **DataContext** of the Window.  In this example, the window is named 'theWindow' (`x:Name="theWindow"`).  Since the source of the **Binding** is the window, the Path must point to the ViewModel in the **DataContext** property on that Window.

We pass the current Model the DataGrid row is bound to into the command.  This way, it is triival to remove it from the collection in the ViewModel.

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> Items {get;set;}

public ICommand RemoveItemCommand {get;set;}

// this method is called when RemoveItemCommand.Execute is called!
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
  Items.Remove(parameter as Model);
}
```

This assumes you're using one of the standard delegated ICommand implementations out there.  You can see how this is trivial to implement, and since the collection is an observable one, once you click the button and the Model is removed, the DataGrid will be notified of the change in the collection and remove that row.

Comment: Thanks Will, I will try this out and let you know... looks like the right solution for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be firing the command in the viewmodel. I am using MVVMLight relaycommand to setup my icommand. When I click the button nothing happens. The xaml is just as you have it as is the viewmodel code. Any ideas why it won't fire?

Comment: The existence of two `Command` attributes on the `Button` element betrays this code as untested.

Comment: I noticed this and I'm sure the second Command was meant to be a CommandParameter instead which is the way I have it, but still now working.

Comment: @RobertRossney: You could have edited instead of being snarky... Thanks, updated (I usually put "this is xaml-like pseudocode" warnings when I code in the edit box...)

Comment: @John: dangit, my auto comment for debugging bindings is not available... Make sure you turn on binding debugger.  debug ->options and settings->debugging->output window->WPF trace settings->Data Binding, set to All.  Then right-click on the Output window while debugging and ensure "Program Output" is checked.

Comment: I certainly wasn't intending to be snarky.  Binding to a command on the owning window is pretty complicated, though, and very unlikely to work without being tested.

Comment: @Robert NP.  My bind is slightly complicated the first time you do it (you have to bind to the DataContext), but if you think that bind is "pretty complicated" and "very unlikely to work without being tested" then you might want to stay with Winforms.  It is almost as trivial as you can get.  Hacking together a collection that listens to events of its contents is more likely to result in unwanted side effects (e.g., memory leaks when you unregister listeners improperly).  But, in fairness, they're but about as simple as you can get.  Mine just requires less coding.

Comment: "You might want to stay with Winforms"?  Seriously?  What you posted is unlikely to work without being tested because *it wasn't tested and it didn't work.*  I regret saying "pretty complicated," because that's vague; what I should have said is that it couples the `DataTemplate` to the window it's used in.  You'll need to fix this when you refactor the data template into a user control.  "Remove" functionality creates a logical dependency between container and item, and that's where the dependency belongs.  Just let the items call `Container.Remove(this)`.  No need for events.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off using the standard routed events on the Click event of the button instead of a Command.  The click event will allow you to retrieve the information about what control was clicked, and then you can also easily retrieve the parent of the button, to delete that item.